# How to sync the scrolling of two listboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a checkedlistbox and a listbox both the same height with the same number of items in them.  I use the listbox to hold status of checkedlistbox a item.

If there's a scrollbar, then scrolling the checkedlistbox should also scroll the listbox with the same index.  I kind of got that working except they scroll at different amounts.

```
private void checkedListBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int scroll = e.Delta / 120;

    if (scroll == 1)
    {
        checkedListBox1.TopIndex -= 5;
        listBox1.TopIndex = checkedListBox1.TopIndex;
    }
    else if (scroll == -1)
    {
        checkedListBox1.TopIndex += 5;
        listBox1.TopIndex = checkedListBox1.TopIndex;
    }
}
```

Additionally, I'm using this code to get the same indexes selected but there's a slight lag until the listbox index gets selected after selecting from the checkedlistbox.  Anyway to make it select at the same time?

```
private void checkedListBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkedListBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        int selected = checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex;
        if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(selected) == false)
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(selected, true);
            listBox1.SetSelected(selected, true);
        }
        else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(selected) == true)
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(selected, false);
            listBox1.SetSelected(selected, true);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can put listboxes inside Two scrollviewer and in the viewChanged event  write the code on xaml.cs part**

```
private void ScrollViewer1_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{        
 ScrollViewer2.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(double.Parse(ScrollViewer1.HorizontalOffset.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/article.php/c4163

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/197335/Synchronized-ListBox-objects-or-how-to-scroll-2-Li